# Laravel contains() for multiple values

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if it is possible to use `contains()` for multiple values.

For example, let's say I have the following `perms` table:

```
  TABLE `perms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  )
```

Example rows:

```
  INSERT INTO `perms` (`id`, `subject`, `action`) VALUES
  (1, 'Product', 'Create'),
  (2, 'Product', 'Read'),
  (3, 'Product', 'Update'),
  (4, 'Product', 'Delete');
```

My users have a `belongsToMany` relationship with a `users_perms` table, where a user can have any number of `perms`.

I want to check if a user has a perm which contains a `subject` AND an `action`. So, I want to check if a user has the perm to `Create` a `Product`.

Right now the following code works when checking just the `action`:

```
  $action = 'Create';
  $user->perms->contains('action', $action); // true if they have ANY Create action perm
```

But I need this to also check the `subject` too, because it isn't enough to just check the `action`. So I need something like:

```
  $subject = 'Product';
  $action = 'Create';
  $user->perms->contains([
    ['subject', $subject],
    ['action', $action],
  ]);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
$user->perms->contains(function ($val, $key) use ($subject, $action) {
    return $val->subject == $subject && $val->action == $action;
});
```

Comment: Very good answer and fast execution.  I measured using `$exist = $user->perms->where('action', $action)->where('subject', $subject)->first(); isset($exist);` methods against your code, while loading the same dataset five times.  Yours averaged `0.076485062` faster.